# Neo4j 2.0.0-M06 with spring-data-neo4j (any version) is throwing NotInTransactionException exception

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

During initialization of spring context following exception is thrown -

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.AbstractTransactionManager.assertInTransaction(AbstractTransactionManager.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.assertInTransaction(IndexManagerImpl.java:465)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.existsForNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.getIndex(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.isAlreadyIndexed(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.chooseStrategy(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.<init>(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(Neo4jConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5891e719.CGLIB$typeRepresentationStrategyFactory$4(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5891e719$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1c91e144.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5891e719.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 97 more
```

How do I get around this?
Neo4j version - 2.0.0-M06

Comment: How are you loading spring context? Show your exception in context of the code that causes it.

Comment: SDN 3.0.M01 has not been released. Previous SDN versions only work with Neo4j 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

it seems current spring neo4j only support version 1.9